# Automated browser testing: How to test JavaScript in web pages?

Tags: .net, javascript, browser, automated-tests

I am trying to write an application that will test a series of web-pages programmatically. The web pages being tested have JavaScript embedded within them which alter the structure of the HTML when they complete execution. It is then the goal to take the final HTML (post-execution of the embedded JavaScript) and compare it against a known output.

Essentially, the Input ---> Output for the test application is:

**URL** ---[*retrieve HTML*]---> **HTML** ---[*execute JS, then compare*]---> **PASS/FAIL**

Here is the challenge:

I have been unable to find a solution that is able to take the HTML I retrieve from the URL and process the JavaScript, as a browser would, and generate the final HTML a user might see from "View Source" on the same page within the browser.

It would be very surprising if this sort of approach has not been made before, so I'm hoping someone out there knows of a fitting solution for this application/problem? If at all possible, I'm hoping for a solution that integrates with .NET (I've tried using the WebBrowser, with no luck). However, if there is an existing 3rd party application that can do exactly this, that would be quite acceptable.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

- Dave

Answer (score 3):

The standard household name for browser based testing is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). It should be able to do what you're looking for.